# DataGridViewComboBox error vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

I'm quite lost in this error I'm getting. I have a Combobox that I added to my dgv, I am able to fill my combo-box with the values I want yet I keep getting an exception when I make a selection change on the dgv itself. Every time I choose a value from the combo box and then perform a selection change on the dgv the error that is thrown is : **DataGridViewComboBoxCell is not valid** . After this error is thrown, the value in the combo box is set to nothing.

This is my first time posting and I've done alot of research for the past two days and I can't seem to get anywhere. If you guys would like me to post my code I will do so. Thanks.

Edit: added my code:

```
cmbItem = New cboItem(dr.Item("strFolderName"), dr.Item("strFolderPath"), dr.Item("strEntryID"))

Dim dtmTmp As Date = oItem.ReceivedTime
dgvEmails.Rows.Insert(intEmailPosition, {False, dtmTmp.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm tt"), GetRecipientEmail(oItem), oItem.subject.ToString, cmbItem, oItem.conversationid.ToString, oItem.entryid.ToString, strFoundBy, oItem.body})

DirectCast(dgvEmails.Rows(intEmailPosition).Cells("cboFileTo"), DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items.Add(cmbItem)
DirectCast(dgvEmails.Rows(intEmailPosition).Cells("cboFileTo"), DataGridViewComboBoxCell).DisplayMember = "DisplayText"
```

This is how I am adding the items into the combobox. Am I doing something wrong?

Edit: Added extra code

```
Dim cellComboBox As ComboBox = TryCast(e.Control, ComboBox)
        RemoveHandler cellComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf Me.cellComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged
        AddHandler cellComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf Me.cellComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged 'trapping the event handler


        If cellComboBox IsNot Nothing Then
            'load all values into the combox box 
            cellComboBox.MaxDropDownItems = 6 'drop down list can only have 5 items in there

            Try
                strEmail = dgvEmails.SelectedRows(0).Cells(2).Value.ToString 'cells(2) holds the email address
                strConvoID = dgvEmails.SelectedRows(0).Cells(5).Value.ToString 'cells(5) holds the conversation id of the email
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
            'call GetSuggestion function here
            objclsSuggesstion.GetSuggestion(strConvoID, strEmail, NUMBER_SUGGESTIONS)

            For intI = 0 To NUMBER_SUGGESTIONS - 1
                dr = objclsSuggesstion.GetItem(intI)
                If dr IsNot Nothing Then
                    'add dr to the combo box
                    cboItem = New cboItem(dr.Item("strFolderName"), dr.Item("strFolderPath"), dr.Item("strEntryID"))


                    'If Not cellComboBox.SelectedItem.FolderEntryID = cboItem.FolderEntryID Then 'if does not exist then add
                    cellComboBox.Items.Add(cboItem)
                    'End If

                Else
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

            'cellComboBox.Items.Add(cboItem)
            cboItem = Nothing 'make object nothing here
            cboItem = New cboItem("", "", "", "<choose folder>...") 'create new object & add

            'if <choose folder>... doesn't exist, then you add it. 
            Try
                If Not cellComboBox.SelectedItem.DisplayText = cboItem.DisplayText Then
                    'cellComboBox.Items.Add(cboItem)
                    'DirectCast(dgvEmails.SelectedRows(0).Cells("cboFileTo"), DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items.Add(cboItem)
                    'DirectCast(dgvEmails.SelectedRows(0).Cells("cboFileTo"), DataGridViewComboBoxCell).DisplayMember = "DisplayText"
                    cellComboBox.Items.Add(cboItem)
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
```

I hope this helps?

Comment: please paste your code

Comment: DisplayText property is a user property inside my object used to display the text inside of the combo box

Comment: It's not easy to understand what's going on. What kind of objects are you adding? How do you get them? is the Combobox bound to a datasource?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, it's a user made object I am adding that has 4 attributes, I'm making the object in a loop before adding to the combo box. The combo box is unbound to a data source Vland.

Comment: Please, post the code where you are adding the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.

Comment: varocarbas, the column is added through the designer. It's a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see all your code, but this is an example about adding a list of objects of type `cmbItem` to a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`

```
Public Class Form1
Dim myItems As New List(Of cmbItem)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    myItems.Add(New cmbItem() With {.Text = "yesterday", .DisplayText = Now.Date.AddDays(-1).ToString()})
    myItems.Add(New cmbItem() With {.Text = "now", .DisplayText = Now.Date.ToString()})
    myItems.Add(New cmbItem() With {.Text = "tomorrow", .DisplayText = Now.Date.AddDays(1).ToString()})


    'find combobox in datagridview, passing column index
    Dim ss = CType(DataGridView1.Columns(1), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)

    'add my items to combobox
    For Each cmbItem As cmbItem In myItems
        ss.Items.Add(cmbItem)
    Next

    'set combobox properties
    ss.ValueMember = "Text"
    ss.DisplayMember = "DisplayText"
End Sub

End Class

Public Class cmbItem
    Property Text() As String
    Property DisplayText() As String
End Class
```

**Result:**

[image]

If you want to add a new row, you must be sure to add a valid combobox value in the comboboxColumn. In the following code...

```
Private Sub AddRow()
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New Object() {"New", myItems.First()})
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New Object() {"New", "12/01/1984"})
End Sub
```

The first row is added correctly, the second one gives and exception like yours **"DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid."**

[image]

There are a lot of ways to add new rows getting a valid combobox item, here are some examples

```
Private Sub AddRow2()
    Dim ss = CType(DataGridView1.Columns(1), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)

    'adding from my list
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New Object() {"New", myItems.First()})


    'adding from current combobox Items
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New Object() {"New", ss.Items.OfType(Of cmbItem).Last()})


    'querying from combobox added items
    Dim queryItem = (From i In ss.Items.OfType(Of cmbItem)() _
                    Where i.Text = "now" _
                    Select i).Single()

    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New Object() {"New", queryItem})

End Sub
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Yes Vland, I am able to get this, but when I click on a different row inside of the datagridview, an exception is raised.

Comment: @RahulKishore It's probably because you're adding that new row with a wrong comboboxcell value.

Comment: @RahulKishore i added some examples. You need to get a valid and existing combobox object before adding the new row

Comment: still not getting anywhere at the moment, but looking @ your post I think I may need to rewrite how I'm adding my combo box items. Thanks I will definitely get back to you soon.

Comment: This is just a way to do it... another good choice is adding a BindingSource to your combobox.datasource and then choosing your value from there when adding a new row.

Comment: Forgot to mention I have multiple items I need to fill into the combobox, maybe this is the reason? Debugging still leads me to nothing. It seems on selection change, the items I added to the combo box are removed.

Comment: @RahulKishore this might be the problem, combobox accept ONE value only. try assigning one and see if it works

Comment: Yes, no error occurs on the first item. Not even on selection change.

Comment: @RahulKishore this solves the matter hopefully... you need other solutions if you want a multi-checked value.